# SASS equivalent to LESS Space ("+_") syntax

Tags: sass

LESS has a great little feature called [Space](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-space) that allows mixins to append rules to existing properties. Really useful for transform() mixins, because you can append many transform rules to the same property, just by calling the mixin multiple times, eg.

Example:

```
.scale() {
  transform+_: scale(2);
}
.rotate() {
  transform+_: rotate(15deg);
}
.myclass {
  .scale();
  .rotate();
}
```

Outputs:

```
.myclass {
  transform: scale(2) rotate(15deg);
}
```

I'm trying to get into SASS, but I don't understand how to achieve this with the available syntax. Whatever I do, the output only ever applies one of the transformations, not both. What is the best way to achieve this behaviour using SASS alone?

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable arguments in a mixin like so:

```
@mixin transform($transforms...) {
  transform: $transforms;
}
.myclass {
  @include transform(scale(0.5) rotate(30deg));
}
```

this will output:

```
.myclass {
  transform: scale(0.5) rotate(30deg);
}
```

You can see a working example here:

http://codepen.io/sonnyprince/pen/RaMzgb

A little more info:

> Sometimes it makes sense for a mixin or function to take an unknown
>   number of arguments. For example, a mixin for creating box shadows
>   might take any number of shadows as arguments. For these situations,
>   Sass supports “variable arguments,” which are arguments at the end of
>   a mixin or function declaration that take all leftover arguments and
>   package them up as a list. These arguments look just like normal
>   arguments, but are followed by ....

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments

Comment: The CSS this answer generates is invalid.  Also, it doesn't really answer the question being asked.

Comment: @cimmanon accidental addition of a comma. Also this is an SCSS alternative - not a direct replacement.

Comment: This does not help the OP if the mixins in question do other things as well as set the transform property.

Answer (score 0):

Sass does not offer such a feature.

You can get reasonably close by using global variables.  However, every single mixin you use, including ones provided by a 3rd party, will have to be modified to work this way.

```
// the setup
$append-property-vals: (); // global variable
$old-append-property-vals: (); // global variable
@mixin append-property($key, $val, $separator: comma) {
    $old-val: map-get($append-property-vals, $key);
    @if $old-val {
        $append-property-vals: map-merge($append-property-vals, ($key: append($old-val, $val, $separator))) !global;
    } @else {
        $append-property-vals: map-merge($append-property-vals, ($key: $val)) !global;
    }
}

@mixin append-properties {
    // cache the original value
    $old-append-property-vals: $append-property-vals !global;
    @content;

    // write out the saved up properties
    @each $key, $val in $append-property-vals {
        #{$key}: $val;
    }

    // restore the original value
    $append-property-vals: $old-append-property-vals !global;
}

// modify the OP's provided mixins to work
@mixin scale {
    // if the vals should be comma delimited, write `comma` instead of `space` for the 3rd argument
    @include append-property(transform, scale(2), space);
}
@mixin rotate {
    @include append-property(transform, rotate(15deg), space);
}

// call the mixins
.myclass {
    @include append-properties {
        @include scale;
        @include rotate;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.myclass {
  transform: scale(2) rotate(15deg);
}
```